# Two identity columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am creating a table in SQL Server with three columns. I want the first two columns to increment counts one by one. I used the first column as identity column that automatically increments 1 when row is inserted. I tried to do the same with second column (but SQL Server does not allow two identity columns per table). I found another way i-e using **Sequence** but since I am using SQL Server 2008, it does not have this feature.

How can I achieve my task?

I am using the first identity column in reports and I reset it when some count is achieved; for example when it reaches 20, I reset it to 1 (Edited). The second incremental column will be used by me for sorting the data and i do not intend to reset it.

```
create table tblPersons
(
    IDCol int primary key identity(1,1),
    SortCol int primary key identity(1,1),
    Name nvarchar(50)
)
```

PS : I cannot copy the values of `IDCol` to `SortCol` because when I reset the `IDCol` to 20 from my code, the `SortCol` will copy the same values (instead it should continue to 21,22,23 and so on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan on incrementing both columns always at the same time, then one workaround here might be to just use a single auto increment column, but use the remainder of that counter divided by 20 for the second value:

```
CREATE TABLE tblPersons (
    IDCol int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name nvarchar(50)
)

SELECT
    IDCol,
    IDCol % 20 AS SortCol    -- this "resets" to zero upon reaching 20
FROM tblPersons;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tim, Your solution is exactly what I needed. The IDCol increment works fine until it hits the count 20 and at 20, the IDCol column resets to 0. Any hints on how can I solve this and avoid 0. (I want it to increment from 1 to 20 and repeat) Snapshot link is also attached below. Thanks again

Snapshot Link : http://prntscr.com/hrq5zz

Comment: @Rizwan606 I updated my answer.  Consider using `(IdCol % 19) + 1` as a formula for the range 1 to 19, with the counter resetting to 1 upon hitting 20.

Comment: You could also just use a windowed function like `row_number()` assuming you aren't just building the table purely for reporting

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sir I hit another issue on the update. The second column starts from 2 now. Even If I select it using the  ((IdCol % 19) + 1) AS SortCol (and using the first answer), the same issue arises. I want to use it from 1 to 20 and then repeat from 1 to 20. Sorry for disturbing you. Screenshot of the update : http://prntscr.com/hrqiis

Comment: @Charleh Sir, I am using the table only for crystal reports. The first column will be used for selecting the data (the sequence in which it was inserted) and second column will be used to display data from 1 to 20 and then again from 1 to 20 numbering.

Comment: Identity columns in SQL Server start at 1, not zero, by default, unless you have changed that default.  I don't entirely follow the new problem you are having, but I still offer my simple solution of using the modulus as an option.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, you can use `Computed Column`

```
create table tblPersons
(
    SortCol int primary key identity(1,1),
    IDCol AS CASE WHEN (SortCol % 20) = 0 THEN 20 ELSE (SortCol % 20) END ,
    Name nvarchar(50)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Serkan, The IDCol increment works fine until it hits the count 20 and at 20, the IDCol column resets to 0. Any hints on how can I solve this and avoid 0. (I want it to increment from 1 to 20 and repeat) Snapshot link is also attached below. Thanks again 

Snapshot Link : prntscr.com/hrq5zz